# Fetching somehow the owner address of a polygon network NFT in opensea?

Tags: ethereum, nft, opensea

I try to fetch the owner address of a NFT which sits in the Polygon Network from OpenSea.io! The problem is that the API from opensea does not support Polygon.

I use the owner address as part of a auth process with MetaMask but I cant figure out any way to get the address except with some type of website **scraping** tool which would be pretty quick and dirty.

Does anyone has an idea how could I get the owner address somehow from polygon?
Here a test NFT from opensea: https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963/25867163425986018856889440957896213450322282376135695915897716851719840727041

Contract is: 0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963
Token ID: 25867163425986018856889440957896213450322282376135695915897716851719840727041

Thx for any tips and ideas in advance

Comment: You'd have to get the abi from polygonscan and call whatever method does that from web3

Comment: Actually no web3 needed. It's simple curl/json calls of the Poliscan API. The problem is that the API does not support any open to get the owner address of a token id. At least i didn't find any open. I do have only contract and token id pairs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm explaining how to do it... Feel free to ignore me I guess.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. Where do I ignore anything? Polygonscan has an API that's correct, to use this API you don't need web3 in my opinion. But either way with the API from Polygonscan I did not find any option to fetch the owner of a specific token_id with the given contract and token_id. Correct me if I am wrong and not seeing things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the abi of the contract (no typo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the moralis sdk for this, checkout this doc -> https://deep-index.moralis.io/api-docs/#/token/getTokenIdOwners

You can get the API key by signing up on moralis and just try it out in the browser on the above link!

Comment: It looks like a comment in place of an answer. It needs more info.

Comment: This worked for me. Just create an account, get your API key, then login with that key and input the contract address and token ID. Works great.

Comment: Is there any api to get NFTs with the given owner_address?